# How to stop auto encoding of <%= strings %> with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using rails 3. In my  index.html.erb and in my index.js.erb, if I have:

```
<%= "string with unsafe characters' like <" %>
```

It will automatically be encoded to:

```
string with unsafe characters&quot; like &amp;
```

just the same as if I had used:

```
<%=h "string with unsafe characters' like <" %>
```

How do I get it to stop? I have stored some short bits of JavaScript that I need to insert into the template without it automatically encoding the string?

Comment: Just for reference, this is a feature of Rails 3.0 called SafeBuffers, http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the `raw` method like this:

```
<%=raw "string with unsafe characters' like <" %>
```